# Can't find "Spellchecking and Writing Aids"setting?

Tags: language-support

Can't find "Spellchecking and Writing Aids"setting in Language support anymore in  Ubuntu 12.4, how could i change this setting now ?

Answer (score 0):

For system wide language go to "system settings > Language Support". For individual programs like libreoffice, open libreoffice and go to "tools > options" which brings up a window and under libreoffice "Language settings > Writing Aids" it has a checkbox for checking while you type.

Comment: I still can't find the option in "Language support"

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Super</kbd> then type *Language*, you should see it:

[image]

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to launch it. Then you will see the "Language Support" app:

[image]

To disable the check spell at specific apps you will have to change the app configuration.

For example, at Firefox go to "Edit" > "Preferences" > "Advanced" > "General" > "Browsing" and uncheck "Check my spelling as I type":

[image]

And at Libreoffice: go to "Tools" > "Language" > "For all text" > "None".

Comment: I still can't find the option in "Language support"

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to uncheck this option "Spellchecking and Writing Aids"

Comment: This is specific in each app. For example at Libreoffice you can go to "Tools" > "Language" > "For all text" > "None"

Comment: i dont think so, it happens also in FF when i type, the words get underlined and i am trying to disable that

Comment: At Firefox, go to "Edit" > "Preferences" > "Advanced" > "Browsing" and uncheck "Check my spelling as I type"

Comment: First thank you for helping me out, i tried that but didn't work, i believe it is related to ispell integration with input methods, also it happens only when i switch to english